# Script stopped working without any recent code changes on the site

Tags: javascript

I have inherited a site and don't really understand the set-up!

The scripts on the site were all working ok then we are suddenly getting script errors and the script that entered a date in a field has stopped working.

this is at the top of the page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setURLs(//domainname/base/administration/);
    </script>
```

I am getting this error:  Unexpected end of input - what do I need to do to fix that?

Then this script:

```
    <script>DateInput('Payment_Date', true, 'yyyy-mm-dd','2022-07-20')</script>
```

is giving the error DateInput is not defined and the field is not been added to the form - how do I sort that?

Answer (score 0):

from the two lines of code that you shared I noticed a problem with

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setURLs(//domainname/base/administration/);
    </script>
```

the `//` means comment so in order to make the function work you need to add some `'` around it

like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setURLs('//domainname/base/administration/');
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks - I have changed it to include the ' but I am still getting the error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: setURLs is not defined"